# in our code quick method is implemented as below? what is the benefit for implementing quick method?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, mvvm-light

Call for quick method is:

```
QuickMethods.IsFullyEmpty(CompanyName.Text) ||
                QuickMethods.IsFullyEmpty(UsernameText.Text) ||
                QuickMethods.IsFullyEmpty(PasswordText.Password)
```

and implementation is:

```
public static class QuickMethods
    {
        public static bool IsFullyEmpty(string s)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim()))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

is there any option available? if yes then how?

Comment: Are `CompanyName`, `UsernameText`, `PasswordText` properties of the `ViewModel`? If yes, then just extract the code as a method.

Comment: It wouldn't work for null string.

Comment: @Serge : HOW CAN extract code as method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main benefit is encapsulating the implementation of IsFullyEmpty.  This improves your design as you are only need to change the implementation of IsFullyEmpty in one component (instead of every component that calls IsFullyEmpty).  As you (or other team members) develop new components, you can avoid bugs down the road that were a result of re-implementing the IsFullyEmpty() logic (ie, the new programmer on your team may forget to Trim() the string first).  There are refactoring benefits as well, for example, if this was a .NET 2.0 project that moved to .NET 4.0, you could refactor IsFullyEmpty to:

```
public static class QuickMethods 
{ 
   public static bool IsFullyEmpty(string s) 
   { 
     return string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume the benefit is that the method also checks for strings containing only whitespace, but if you're looking for an "option", then in .NET 4.0 you could use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` and avoid the call to `Trim()`.

Comment: You should add that, i case when `s` is `null` the NullReferenceException will be thrown

Answer (score 1):

Why not extract this validation logic into a method (or property)?

```
class TheViewModel
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string UsernameText { get; set; }
    public string PasswordText { get; set; }

    private bool Validate()
    {
        bool result = !QuickMethods.IsFullyEmpty(CompanyName) &&
                !QuickMethods.IsFullyEmpty(UsernameText) &&
                !QuickMethods.IsFullyEmpty(PasswordText);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is far more readable than the combined IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim())

An improved version would provide some feedback as to what is wrong.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked; it's at best a comment to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the advantage of [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

```
public static class QuickMethods
    {
        public static bool IsFullyEmpty(this string s, params string[] others)
        {

            if(s != null && s.trim().length > 0) {
               return false;
            }

            for(String o : others) {
              if(o != null && o.trim().length > 0)) {
               return false;
              }
            }

            return true;         
        }
    }
```